# Div width jumps around sporadically whens set to a percentage, before settling on the assigned width

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery to animate the width of a div to be 100% of the screen. The problem is, once the div *visually* expands to that width, the actual value of the width % jumps around sporadically before eventually settling on the value of 100% I assigned it. The problem can be seen in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vj_qZ6j8iYI&feature=youtu.be) video I recorded.

Visually, the element still works fine — the width does not appear to change at all. The problem is, the parallax scrolling plugin (skrollr) I am using will glitch and flicker the div when srolling, until the value is finally settled (I've tried removing skrollr for a control test). The jumping around effect only occurs when setting it to a percentage or vw, setting it to an exact value in px works fine.

Here's the div I'm controlling

```
<div class="projectContainer" id="A Head In The Box">
        <table class="projectTitle"><td align="right" valign="bottom" ></table>
        <div class="circle"></div><div class="circle"></div><div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

And the code controlling the animation

```
$(selProject).animate({
            left:'0px',
            top:'0px',
            width:'100%',
            height:'650px',},600,"easeOutQuint");
```

I've tried stripping out every bit of code except for this animation, but it still seems to be doing it even then. I rebuilt the div, and got a barebones working version [here](http://grahamhartnell.com/testing.html), if you'd like to view the source. I you wan to see the non-working, full verison of the site, that's [here](http://grahamhartnell.com).

Comment: the sporadic part would be the easing you have set

Comment: @charlietfl Can't be, the same easing is set in the stripped down testing link I provided, where it works fine. I just tried taking it out regardless, and it's still happening.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I've managed to solve it, but in one of those roundabout ways where I'm not entirely sure *why* it's solved.

The animation was encased in a function that would only occur when all the other "projectContainer"s had faded out, ie:

```
$(".projectContainer").not(selProject).fadeOut(200,"swing", function(){
   $(selProject).animate({
            left:'0px',
            top:'0px',
            width:'100%',
            height:'650px',},600,"easeOutQuint");
})
```

When I removed that, and just set the animation up with a delay so that it would happen after the other elements had faded out, it miraculously worked. If anyone happens to know how that made the width of the element jump around by hundreds of percent, I'd love to know :P